# Kernel Update leads to xOrg error

Tags: arch-linux, kernel

Basically every time I update to a new kernel using `pacman -Syyu`, the output of `pacman -Q linux && uname -r` does not correspond with each other. Example:

```
[alexander_schoch@Arch: ~]$ pacman -Q linux && uname -r
linux 4.15.7-1
4.15.6-1-ARCH
```

After a reboot, the system cannot start xOrg anymore, as it crashes with the error `no screens fount [EE]`. Every time this occurs, i have to boot into a live stick of arch, chroot into my system and run `pacman -Sy linux` which updates it to the newest verstion. What am I doing wrong?

#### EDIT 2:

```
[alexander_schoch@Arch: ~]$ cat /etc/fstab
# Static information about the filesystems.
# See fstab(5) for details.

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
```

Comment: That generally indicates `/boot` was not mounted for the kernel upgrade.

Comment: @jasonwryan I manually mounted the partition using `mount /dev/sda5 /boot` and run `pacman -Syyu linux` afterwards. The problem still occurs.

Comment: Yes, but are you sure it is mounted when the kernel is first upgraded? If it isn't, the second `-Syyu linux` will not fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by that? After `mount /dev/sda5 /boot`, the partition should definitely be mounted, but how can I go for sure?

Comment: Because the update has already failed and the modules replaced; it won't work again unless you chroot in or update from a live media with the --root option.

Comment: Oh, I see... sorry, I did not know that it necessairily has to be mounted by the first time. Just to prevent further problems: Do you also know why my boot partition is not mounted at startup? How do I fix that?

Comment: It is mounted at starrup, but systemd will unmount it after inactivity. Paste your `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: as you can see, my fstab is empty. But that shouldn't be a problem. The boot partition does not necessairily have to be mounted, as I have a shortcut command to install software and update my system. I can just insert `mount` and `umount` commands into the bash file.

Comment: It *has* to be mounted for kernel updates. If you don't put it in `/etc/fstab`, then it is on you to ensure it is mounted (and some janky bash script is not a robust approach, IMO).

Comment: Okay, I just updated it via stick and added `/dev/sda5` to `/etc/fstab`, so everything should be fine now. Thank you so much!